# Heroku domain doesn't work

Tags: heroku, dns, subdomain

I go to freenom create the free domain name:  mydomain.ga

And the dns target at dashboard in heroku is mydomain.ga.herokudns.com

So I go to DNS MANAGEMENT

Name: any name

Type: CNAME

TTL:14440

Target:mydomain.ga.herokudns.com

But When I connect to www.mydomain.ga

And it has the error about can not find out the server.

What was I missed?

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed .

1. `heroku domains:add www.mydomain.ga`
2. `heroku domains:add mydomain.ga`
3. IN the freenom's Target: www.mydomain.ga.herokudns.com